# Applet not displaying from appletviewer

Tags: java, applet, awt, appletviewer

When i run the *Main00App.java* from appletviewer i have *Start: applet not initiated*.
The commented html is read because i can resize the window using the width and height.

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.applet.*;

/*
<applet code="Main00App.class" width=200 height=150>
</applet>
*/

public class Main00App extends Applet {

public void paint(Graphics g) {
    g.drawString("Java applet", 10, 20);
}

}
```

Comment: 1) Why code an applet?  If it is due to the teacher specifying it, please refer them to [Why CS teachers should **stop** teaching Java applets](http://programmers.blogoverflow.com/2013/05/why-cs-teachers-should-stop-teaching-java-applets/). 2) Why use AWT?   See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6255106/java-gui-listeners-without-awt/6255978#6255978) for many good reasons to abandon AWT using components in favor of Swing.

Answer (score 1):

I think so that you need to run following program by command line using the applet viewer:

```
appletviewer Main00App.java
```

I had run the following program. It works for me.